# Swift optionals require nil? unable to use break?

Tags: swift

I understand the importance of optionals (allowing a code to run, and not crash if receiving nil) however what I don't understand, is-- if that's the case why I'm required to specify nil.

If I choose not to return anything- isn't that the same as returning Nil? This also begs the question, why does my switch need to be exhaustive? If an error would just return Nil.

I understand an optional is more used for when pulling (for example) information from an array-- in case the inputted index doesn't exist/isn't found... but how is not finding a result any different than not returning anything.

Example:

```
func example(#name: Int) -> Int? {
case 1: 
    // do x
case 2:
    // do y
    return y
}
```

or even, if it needs a default (even though it would be able to return nil as it's returning an optional)

```
func example(#name: Int) -> Int? {
case 1: 
    // do x
case 2:
    // do y
    return y
default: 
    break
}
```

Instead it is requiring

```
func example(#name: Int) -> Int? {
case 1: 
    // do x
    return nil
case 2:
    // do y
    return y
default
    return nil 
}
```

Now you might be asking-- why this matters-- couldn't I just specify nil-- or even better, not use an optional and just set a 'holder' value to = "" and then return that value and skip out on the optionals altogether. Yes! I absolutely could, but i'm trying to understand swift's logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not returning anything is the same as returning Void (or empty tuple), so it's not the same as returning nil.

nil is equivalent to Optional.None, where Optional is an enumeration type.

You can prove this in Playground:

```
print(nil === Optional.None)       // "true\n"
print(Void.self == ().dynamicType) // "true\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not the same. If you don't return anything. It means you actually return `Void`, and `Void` is not `Int?`

when you create a function like `func doSomething()`, actually it is  `func doSomething() -> Void`

Comment: So is it possible to return one of two types? Example: void OR string **or** string OR Int?

Comment: Yes, you can return any type you want. func foo() -> Any